# How to compare a array of strings with strcmp?

Tags: c

I have the code below, and I'm trying to compare the content of `arrayx` with `argv[2]` (user input argument upon execution), however even when the `argv[2]` matches with the content of `arrayx`, it bypasses to the else statement.

If I try to use:

```
strcpy(arg3, "inputstring" );
```

Then it works.

Also, if I try to `printf(%s, arrayx)`, it prints out the correct string.

Any idea why it does not work when I try to use the arrayx variable on strcmp ?

```
float float_arrayx[] = {                                                  
    0x69, 0x6e, 0x70, 0x75, 0x74, 0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x0a                                                     
        };                                                                        
unsigned char arrayx[sizeof(float_arrayx) / sizeof(*float_arrayx)];       
                                                                           
for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof(arrayx) / sizeof(*arrayx); j++) {           
    arrayx[j] = (unsigned char)float_arrayx[j];                             
}                                                                         

                                                                           
if (argc == 3 && (strcmp(argv[1], arg_help))) {                        
    char arg3[100];                                                      
    char arg2[32];                                                       
    strcpy(arg3, arrayx );                                               
    strcpy(arg2, "-exec");                                              
    if(!strcmp(argv[1], arg2)) {                              
                                                                           
        if(!strcmp(argv[2], arg3))                                
        {                                         
            printf("\nDO SOMETHING....\n");
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a null-terminator stored in `arrayx` so it's not a valid string for `strcmp` (or any other standard library string function)

Comment: hmm do you know how can I add the null terminator? The odd thing is that I can printf arrayx with no issues.

Comment: Simply increase the size of `arrayx` by 1 and add a `'\0'` at the last index?

Comment: Why are you storing character numbers in an array of `float`?

Comment: I need to store it on a float array in order to prevent the content from being easily seen if someone runs a strings command against the binary file

Comment: @UnholySheep do you know how can I add the '\0' at the last index? I'm struggling....

Comment: If I run a sizeof(arrayx) I see it has the number of chars of the string +1, but I really don't know how to add the null terminator char to the array.

Answer (score 0):

`arrayx` has the length of the float array, so it has one character space for every item in the array. But C strings are null-terminated (the last char must be `\0`), so if you want to use them with the standard string library functions, you need to get `arrayx` null-terminated. That means its size will need to be 1 greater. I'm not sure if you need to manually set the last space to zero, so I would just in case:

```
unsigned char arrayx[sizeof(float_arrayx) / sizeof(*float_arrayx) + 1];       
                                                                           
for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof(float_arrayx) / sizeof(*float_arrayx); j++) {           
    arrayx[j] = (unsigned char)float_arrayx[j];                             
}

arrayx[sizeof(float_arrayx) / sizeof(*float_arrayx) + 1] = 0;
```

I'm also not familiar with `arg_help` so I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but it should be a start.

Comment: If I run a sizeof I see the length of arrayx as +1, example:
string has 6 characters and sizeof shows 7.
I'm not sure what can I do to fix this

````
./a.out -exec string
array --> string
Length of given string is: 7
sizeof(arrayx) = 7
````

Answer (score 0):

Taking no responsibility for the rest of the code, there's this...

To circumvent the "terminating null" problem, perhaps one could use

```
// You use sizeof for filling char array
size_t lenPswd = sizeof arrayx/sizeof arrayx[0];

// Use sizeof for comparing bytes, not two strings
if( strncmp( argv[2], arrayx, lenPswd ) == 0 )
```

Write code for clarity, not for density... The compiler will optimise as it does, but the reader shouldn't be expected to "notice" and parse the meaning of "!" applied to the return value. Be clear...